# How to log into SmartDashBoard?

Tags: linux, checkpoint

I installed the CheckPoint SecurePlatform R75.20 on my VirtualBox. I configured it. Now in order to **create** an OPSEC Application and proceed to maintaining a LEA server, i need to login to **SmartDash** Board. I define me (i.e my ip) as a **GUI client**, and tried to login to the SmartDash Board using the **administrator usename and password** (this is what needs to be done). But the login gets rejected saying "either host is dowm or user not a GUI client". In my case, host is up, as im ssh'ing into it and i have clearly mentioned my ip as a GUI client.

Where have i gone wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: This is not a programing questions, it seams, it'll be best to direct it to a Checkpoint forum (I know there is one, but I can't remember the name)

Answer (score 0):

To be able to logon to a CheckPoint SmartCenter you will have to;

- Have network access to TCP port 18190 (CPMI) from your machine to the SmartCenter (which you probably have since its on your own LAB-network).
- A username/password, which you created during the installation or can add or modify later using the command "cpconfig" and going to menu option "Administrator". (Note: only 1 administrator can be defined using cpconfig. Future administrators is defined inside SmartDashboard).
- Your IP-address must be in the GUI client list. You can modify this by logging on to the SmartCenter machine with SSH, enter command "cpconfig" and go to menu option "GUI Clients".